# python 2.7 executable that was compiled for WinPE 4.0 doesnt work in Latest WinPE

Tags: python, debugging, winpe

We are currently trying to migrate this python executable from an older WinPE to the latest one.This is because we cant find a way to add support for generic NVME drives to the older WinPE 4 environment.

And as such the program we want to use isn't working correctly.Note that is based on Python 2.7

As such we decided to use DISM on windows to migrate the program that we use from the WinPE 4 it was running on to winPE 10 we created. We copied the python executable, the startnet.cmd script along with the.ini and folders necessary for the program to operate. And it does until the point where it returns two error depending on the input

THe first one is this while it is running

Note this is the last error that triggers some other ones on a higher level

```
File"M:\build\pyi.win32\program\out00-PYZ.pyz\wizardpanel'", line 123 ,onNext
File"M:\build\pyi.win32\program\out00-PYZ.pyz\wizards",line 110, in enter
File"M:\build\pyi.win32\program\out00-PYZ.pyz\wx._core",line 11849, in Append
File"M:\build\pyi.win32\program\out00-PYZ.pyz\encodings.cp1252",line15, in decode
    UnicodeDecodeError:'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 19:character maps to <undefined>
```

We can bypass this error by running the program using different parameters, but then when we interact with it and it tries to kill a process we get the following error

```
File"M:\build\pyi.win32\program\out00-PYZ.pyz\progd", line 102 , in __kill_program
File"M:\build\pyi.win32\program\out00-PYZ.pyz\progd", line 85 ,in __kill_program
File"M:\build\pyi.win32\program\out00-PYZ.pyz\win32.com.client",line72, in GetObject
File"M:\build\pyi.win32\program\out00-PYZ.pyz\win32com.client",line 87, in Moniker
    com_error:(-2147221020,'Invalid Syntax',None,None)
```

This second error freezes the program.

Note that this program is used on a WinPE from a flash drive.
ITs job is to provide BMR to the pc it is running on , meaning it connects to a backup server and restores a backup to the PC it is currently running

From what i understand both of these errors are related to encoding.

But i dont know where to start regarding to that, i mean this is a python executable that has all of its dependencies complied to it. Could it be that some of them will only work on WinPE 4 (windows 8 based) instead of WinPE10(windows 10 based)?

I dont really have the exact source code but i have used exe2py and uncompile6 to get to most of. What i really wanna know is if refactoring is the only option or if this could be fixed in an easier way.

Comment: You cut out most of the traceback but there seems to be a bad character (`0x90`), either in your code or in some data you are decoding.

Comment: Remember,this program works in WinPE 4 with no issue . So regarding the first error you are refering, i cant understand why  there would be a bad character . And how would i test this in Windows 10 enviroment. Also i will add the rest of the traceback for both errors if that is a help.